# NLS_CHARACTERSET in nls_session_parameters returns None

Tags: oracle, nscharacterset, character-set, nls-lang

An application I'm using with Oracle seems to be having issues with characters, and I ran the queries below to check on the CHARACTERSET.

- `SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE PARAMETER='NLS_CHARACTERSET';`
- `SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE PARAMETER='NLS_CHARACTERSET';`

The second query from nls_database_parameters returns **AL32UTF8**.

But the first query seems to return **None**.

I've read that the **nls_session_parameters** takes precedence over the **nls_database_parameters**, but in this case, where there does not seem to be any value set for it, would it fall back to the **nls_database_parameters**, or is there something that needs to be configured to set the **nls_session_parameters**.

Thank you for any input on this.

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch3globenv.htm#i1006431)

> NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS shows the NLS parameters and their values for the session that is querying the view. It does not show information about the character set.

Basically `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` will not have Parameter called `NLS_CHARACTERSET`.

The character set is part of the locale, which is determined by the value of `NLS_LANG`.

> NLS_LANG is set as an environment variable on UNIX platforms. NLS_LANG is set in the registry on Windows platforms.

Hence check the `NLS_LANG`. Also this information is picked up by the client application at startup time, and cannot be changed from within.

Answer (score 0):

The `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is the character set which is used by the **database**. Your session (i.e. the client) does not store anything, thus `NLS_CHARACTERSET` does not exist.

I assume you are looking for `NLS_LANG` which tells the database which character set is used by the client. You cannot query `NLS_LANG` from any database view/table, you have to check settings in your client. You can set `NLS_LANG` only at your client side, not at database side.

Note, some clients (e.g. Java JDBC based clients) do not use `NLS_LANG` setting, they use a different globalization mechanism.